# movefile() fails error 2 or 123

Tags: c++

I'm updating a c++ routine to move files that was written in visual studio express 2008/2010.  I'm now running VS Express 2012

Obviously there are changes to the compiler because string functions have to be upgraded to strcpy_s etc.  No problem.    This is a console app.   I never extended my C++ knowledge past C++ to C# etc. as I need little more than to be able to write small utils to do things on the command line. Still I'm able to write somewhat complex utilities.

My issue is movefile() function always fails to move with either error 2 or 123.   I'm working in C:\users\alan\downloads folder so I know I have permission.  I know the file is there.  Small snippet of code is:

```
char source=".\\test.txt";     // edited for clarity.
char dest=".\\test.txt1";
printf("\nMove\n    %s\n to %s\n",source,dest);   // just to see what is going on
MoveFile((LPCWSTR) source, (LPCWSTR) dest);
printf("Error %u\n",GetLastError());
```

output is :
Move
    .\test.txt
 to .\test.txt1
Error 2

All of my strings are simple char strings and I'm not exactly sure, even after reading, what LPCWSTR was type def'd for and if this is the culprit.   So to get this to compile I simply typedef'd my strings.   And it compiles.  But still it won't move the files.
The code is more complex in developing the source & dest variables but I've reduce it to a simple "just append a 1 to the file name" situation to see if I can just simply rename it.  I thought C:\xxx\yyy\zzz\test.txt was maybe wrong in some fashion but that idea fell though with the above test.  I've done it with and without the .\  same issue.    I'm running out of ideas other than making my own fileopen read/write binary function to replace movefile().   I'm really against that but if I have to I will.

EDIT:  I pasted the printf from original code that used FullPathName, I've corrected the snippet.

Comment: Any chance that you're using a single backslash rather than two consecutive backslashes in any of your constant strings? If you're expecting users to be able to help you out here, then you should add the "code to put strings in both variables", as well as the initialization of the `FullPathName` variable and the `newfilename` variable, to your question.

Comment: You need to convert char* to WCHAR* `MoveFile((CA2W(source), CA2W(dest));` or use `MoveFileA`

Comment: @AlexFarber CA2W is ATL/MFC specific and not available in the VS Express editions.

Comment: You can't just cast single-byte to wide character strings. Also, use [`FormatMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351(v=vs.85).aspx) to convert Windows error codes to descriptive strings. You can also [look them up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381(v=vs.85).aspx). 2 is "File not found.", 123 is "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Comment: [If you have to cast, you're probably doing something wrong](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/10/23/9911891.aspx).  "There, that shut up the compiler. Those compiler guys are so stupid. They can't even figure out how to convert one [function] pointer to another. I bet they need help wiping their butts when they go to the bathroom." (via [Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/05/06/10161590.aspx))

Comment: @drescherjm Excellent point. I hope I did not inconvenience you.

Comment: @JasonC No, my comment was more aimed at the OP editing the question long after the correct answer was given. I am not sure if the OP does not understand the answer and is looking for a different answer or just wants to improve the question however either way the correct answer was given.

Comment: To all, thanks for the comments.  This is the first time I've posted a question, sorry for any ambiguities or omissions in the question.   I had already looked up the error codes and found them to be incorrect (file not found when it was there) so that made it obvious I was not working with movefile() properly.  I should have added something like this to the question to clarify.  Life goes on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that you are casting your arguments to `LPCWSTR` suggests that you are compiling your program with `UNICODE` defined, which means you are calling `MoveFileW` and the compiler warned about an argument type mismatch.

Inserting a cast does not fix that. You are telling the compiler to stop complaining, but you haven't actually fixed the problem (the underlying data is still wrong).

Actual solutions:

1. Use `WCHAR` as `MoveFileW` expects (or `TCHAR`/`LPTSTR` and the `_T` macro).
2. Explicitly call `MoveFileA`
3. Compile without `UNICODE` defined.

Comment: Although not appropriate for non-constant strings (e.g. filenames, typically), don't forget about Windows' `LPTSTR` type and `_T` macro for string literals. `LPTSTR name = _T("constant")` will do the appropriate thing based on if `UNICODE` is defined or not.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Andrew Medico.   I used MoveFileA and the program seems to work now.
I'm not sure I turned off unicode, but I did change one item in the properties.

I'll need to read up on the compiler about unicode/ansi settings.   But for now the issue is fixed and I'm sure I've got the idea of what I need to do.   "research"!!!!